# Select option logic on a cloned element

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, clone

The JQuery below displays a hidden div whenever "volume" is selected from my drop-down select. The problem is when I clone the div that wraps the drop-down, the logic only works on the original div and the hidden div gets displayed underneath the original and cloned divs.

Nothing happens when I select "volume" from my cloned element.

```
$('.hiddenBreak').hide();

$('select.discount').change(function(){
    if ($('.discount').val() == 'volume') {
            $('.hiddenBreak').slideToggle('medium');
        } else {
            $('.hiddenBreak').slideUp('fast');
        };
});

<div>
    <select class="discount">
       <option value="volume">Volume</option>
       <option value="nothing">Nothing</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="hiddenBreak">
  Message goes here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if ($('.discount').val() == 'volume') {
        $('.hiddenBreak').slideDown('medium');
    } else {
        $('.hiddenBreak').slideUp('fast');
    }
```

I think having `.toggleSlide()` in there might be messing you up.

Also the line `$('hiddenBreak').hide();` is probably not doing anything, if you want to hide that div, you'll need to replace that with `$('.hiddenBreak').hide();`

Comment: If you put break points in the `if` and the `else` block, are they reached?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to fix this I think as your binding happens before the creation of the cloned element.

```
$('select.discount').live('change', function() {
    if ($('.discount').val() == 'volume') {
            $('.hiddenBreak').slideToggle('medium');
        } else {
            $('.hiddenBreak').slideUp('fast');
        };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting the same results with this solution.